# If $x\sin A+y\sin B+z\sin C=x^2\sin2A+y^2\sin2B+z^2\sin 2C=0$, show $x^3\sin3A+y^3\sin3B+z^3\sin 3C=0$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I'm having trouble with a question that came in one of my exam and is about complex numbers and trigonometry:

> If $$x \sin A +y \sin B+z\sin C=0$$ and $$x^2 \sin 2A + y^2 \sin 2B + z^2 \sin 2C=0$$ then prove that $$x^3 \sin 3A+y^3 \sin 3B +z^3 \sin 3C=0$$ where $x$, $y$, $z$ belong to $\mathbb{R}$ and $A+B+C=\pi$.

**What I tried:** I tried maybe doing it as imaginary part of $xe^{iA} + ye^{iB} +ze^{iC} =0$ and similarly, but I'm reaching a dead end in that approach

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows of the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time explaining what you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of effort tends to give the wrong impression.) If this is from an exam, you must have *some* idea how to proceed.

Comment: Are $A$,$B$,$C$ angles of a triangle?

Comment: well it is not mentioned

Answer (score 3):

If $\sin{C}=0$, so $$x\sin{A}+y\sin(180^{\circ}k-A)=0,$$ where $k$ is an integer number.

Thus, easy to show (just consider two cases: $k$ is odd and $k$ is even) that $$x^3\sin3A+y^3\sin(540^{\circ}k-3A)=0.$$
Now, let $\prod\limits_{cyc}\sin{A}\neq0.$

Thus, the first condition gives $$z=-\frac{x\sin{A}+y\sin{B}}{\sin(A+B)}$$ and with the second we obtain:
$$(x^2\sin2A+y^2\sin2B)\sin(A+B)=2(x\sin{A}+y\sin{B})^2\cos(A+B)$$ or
$$(\sin{A}\cos{A}\sin(A+B)-\sin^2A\cos(A+B))x^2-2\sin{A}\sin{B}\cos(A+B)xy+$$
$$+(\sin{B}\cos{B}\sin(A+B)-\sin^2B\cos(A+B))=0$$ or
$$\sin{A}\sin{B}(x^2-2xy\cos(A+B)+y^2)=0$$ or
$$x^2-2xy\cos(A+B)+y^2=0,$$ which since $|\cos(A+B)|\neq1,$ gives $$x=y=0.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: yes  now i can do it thank u

Comment: @Hrishith Thadicherla You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

With $\alpha=xe^{iA}$, $\beta=ye^{iB}$ and $\gamma=ze^{iC}$ one has $\alpha\beta\gamma=-xyz$, which is a real number. Also, the first two equations of the problem imply that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma$ and $\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2$ are real numbers, so $\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha= \frac 12((\alpha+\beta+\gamma)^2-(\alpha^2+\beta^2+\gamma^2))$ is real as well. Therefore, the polynomial $$(X-\alpha)(X-\beta)(X-\gamma)=X^3-(\alpha+\beta+\gamma)X^2+(\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha)X-\alpha\beta\gamma$$ has real coefficients and either all its roots are real or there is one real root and the other two roots are each other's complex conjugate.

In both cases it follows for all positive $n$ that $\alpha^n+\beta^n+\gamma^n$ is real, which is equivalent with $x^n \sin nA+y^n \sin nB +z^n \sin nC=0$.